# How I can filter records between two combo boxes in Microsoft Access 2010 with After_Update command?See below the code what I have tried.Thanks

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I'm filtering from cmbSites the code is filtering the sites, but when I'm trying to filter selected sites with cmOsha it displaying only OshaType records

```
Private Sub cmbSite_AfterUpdate()
  On Error Resume Next

  Dim MySite As String
  MySite = " Select * from tbl_tracker WHERE ([Location] = '" & Me.cmbSite & "')"
 Me.tbl_tracker_subform.Form.RecordSource = MySite
End Sub

Private Sub cmOsha_AfterUpdate()
  On Error Resume Next

  Dim MySite As String

    MySite = " Select * from tbl_tracker WHERE ([OshaType] = '" & Me.cmOsha & "')"

    Me.tbl_tracker_subform.Form.RecordSource = MySite
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are resetting the recordsource to a single criteria after each AfterUpdate. You probably need to combine them in one call. Here's how to do that.

Create a new function to handle both Location and Osha

```
Function FilterSubform(strSite as String, strOsha as String)
  dim MySite as String
  MySite = " Select * from tbl_tracker WHERE ([Location] = '" & strSite & "' AND [OshaType] = '" & strOsha & "')"
  Me.tbl_tracker_subform.Form.RecordSource = MySite
End Function
```

Update the code in both AfterUpdates to call the same function

```
Private Sub cmbSite_AfterUpdate()
  Call FilterSubform(Me.cmbSite, Me.cmOsha)
End Sub

Private Sub cmOsha_AfterUpdate()
  Call FilterSubform(Me.cmbSite, Me.cmOsha)
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error '94', Invalis use of null ...Call FilterSubform(Me.cmbSite, Me.cmOsha)

Comment: Yes, you can't query on nulls; your code would produce the same error. Decide whether or not you would like to allow for one or both values to be ignored and add/edit the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but I would like to correct code of PractLogical for future visitors not ot get "Invalid use of null" error:

```
Function FilterSubform(strSite As String, strOsha As String)
    Dim MySite As String, strSiteSQL As String, strOshaSQL As String, andSQL As String
    MySite = "SELECT * FROM tbl_tracker "
    If Not IsEmpty(strSite) Or Not IsEmpty(strOsha) Then
      If Not IsEmpty(strSite) Then strSiteSQL = "[Location] = '" & strSite & "' "
      If Not IsEmpty(strOsha) Then strOshaSQL = "[OshaType] = '" & strOsha & "' "
      If Not IsEmpty(strSite) And Not IsEmpty(strOsha) Then andSQL = " AND "
      MySite = MySite & " WHERE " & strSiteSQL & andSQL & strOsha
    End If
    Me.tbl_tracker_subform.Form.RecordSource = MySite
End Function
```